# Finding XPath expression to data element in Workday

Tags: xpath, workday-api

Is there a mode or tool in Workday that can help me determine the XPath for a specific data element within a larger XML blob?  I am on a project in which I need to extract various attributes from Worker_Data information, but due to technical limitations on the client side, I am unable to secure capable assistance with this task.

I simply want to know which data type and identifier corresponds to an item on the screen, and some clues as to the path to that element within the larger item.

I am a complete Workday newbie with almost no access to a working system.

Comment: Within the Workday application there isn't a "tool". What Workday allows you to do, is to create a container to which then you can apply an XSLT transformation, and get object properties, apply transformations, etc, and if required passed the result to another container. Suggest you get Community access and read about the various integration options.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the WSDL from the public part of the Community web site.

[Human Resources V29.0 is available.](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v29.0/Human_Resources.html)

Download the WSDL, open it in SOAPUI and then you can look at the XML to get the path you need in XPATH or use a tool that lets you get XPATH statements to a node.  My boss likes a Chrome extension, and I have a Firefox one. Many such tools exist, search and pick one you like.